# How to make carrier wave uploader can get link of image for API in rails admin dashboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, rails-admin

Now i having problem about my rails admin dashboard. I have use carrier wave for image uploader on my dashboard. It can be work for image uploader on my dashboard, but in the existing image API has been uploaded, they only show **the path of my images not the links** for images has been uploaded. If the API accessed by client. it can't be show the image that i have been uploaded, like this:

```
{
  "status": "200",
  "message": "OK",
  "data": [
{
  "id": 5,
  "category_name": "Marketplace",
  "hex_color": "#f0974a",
  "icon": {
  "url": "/uploads/category/icon/5/ffffff"
}
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "category_name": "Finance",
  "hex_color": "#28ad60",
  "icon": {
  "url": "/uploads/category/icon/4/ffffff"
}
```

So how i can solve the problem of the url that image uploaded can be displayed by API client?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Are you asking how to turn the "url" in the json payload into an actual URL?  How is "url" being set?

Comment: @MarcTalbot yes, i asking about carrier wave uploader then i can access the image API link image not a path  that i have uploaded.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `#url` method rather than the `#path` method when you construct that json object.

`> model.photo_1.path`

`=> "uploads/photo/1234/original/some_file_name.jpg"`

`> model.photo_1.url`

`=> "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/photo/1234/orignal/some_file_name.jpg"`